# Django setUpTestData() vs. setUp()

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Django 1.8 shipped with [a refactored TestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#testcase-data-setup) which allows for data initialization at the class level using transactions and savepoints via the [setUpTestData()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) method. This is in contrast to unittest's [setUp()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUp) which runs before every single test method.

Question: **What is the use case for `setUp()` in Django now that `setUpTestData()` exists?**

I'm looking for objective, high-level answers only, as otherwise this question would be too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It's not uncommon for there to be set-up code that can't run as a class method. One notable example is the Django [test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#the-test-client): you might not want to reuse the same client instance across tests that otherwise share much of the same data, and indeed, the client instances automatically included in subclasses of Django's `SimpleTestCase` are [created per test method](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.2/django/test/testcases.py#L201) rather than for the entire class. Suppose you had a test from the pre-Django 1.8 world with a `setUp` method like this:

```
    def setUp(self):
        self.the_user = f.UserFactory.create()
        self.the_post = f.PostFactory.create(author=self.the_user)
        self.client.login(
            username=self.the_user.username, password=TEST_PASSWORD
        )
        # ... &c.
```

You might tempted to modernize the test case by changing `setUp` to `setUpTestData`, slapping a `@classmethod` decorator on top, and changing all the `self`s to `cls`. But that will fail with a `AttributeError: type object 'MyTestCase' has no attribute 'client'`! Instead, you should use `setUpTestData` for the shared data and `setUp` for the per-test-method client:

```
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        cls.the_user = f.UserFactory.create()
        cls.the_post = f.PostFactory.create(author=cls.the_user)
        # ... &c.

    def setUp(self):
        self.client.login(
            username=self.the_user.username, password=TEST_PASSWORD
        )
```

Note: if you are wondering what that variable **f** is doing in the example code, it comes from [factoryboy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - a useful fixtures library for creating objects for your tests.

Comment: Worth adding some more detail from this approach https://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2015/how-to-optimize-django-unit-tests-with-setuptestdata. If you have test data that changes per-test, you can still create mutable models in `setUpTestData`, as long as you do `self.model.refresh_from_db()` in your `setUp`. The changes from a TC are rolled back, but without that manual step the self.model references the previous run's data. With the setUp step, you do a read per test case, but usually that's faster than doing a write per test case.

Comment: Thanks, diving into an existing django project and was not aware of the per-test method!

Answer (score 46):

Taken from the testing tutorial [Django Tutorial Part 10: Testing a Django web application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Testing#Views):

> - `setUpTestData()` is called once at the beginning of the test run for class-level setup. You'd use this to create objects that aren't going to be modified or changed in any of the test methods.
> - `setUp()` is called before every test function to set up any objects that may be modified by the test (every test function will get a "fresh" version of these objects).

Comment: as of Django 3.2 I think the setUpTestData could be also used for creating in memory objects that would be modified. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 6):

Caches issues. Even if Django gets better at providing test isolation with transaction rollback, caches are still generated and cleared manually.

[edit] : 
SetUpTestData defines the state the DB will be restored to after each test, and does so with a method that is executed only once, transaction rollback being done behind the curtain by Django. This does not work for caches. If you want the cache to be the same for each test, you need to reset it between each test, thus the need for setUp. Django can rollback the DB but can't rollback everything.

(Thank you bryan-oakley for the suggestion )

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question that was asked.

Comment: SetUpTestData defines the state the DB will be restored to after each test, and does so with a method that is executed only once, transaction rollback being done behind the curtain by Django. This does not work for caches. If you want the cache to be the same for each test, you need to reset it between each test, thus the need for setUp. Django can rollback the DB but can't rollback everything.

Comment: You should make your comment part of the answer, because it makes the answer much more understandable.