# Django test setup not being used

Tags: django

I am using Django cookiecutter 1.11 for a project.
Trying to write some basic tests for a model. But the setup method is not being used in the test cases.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from myapp.users.models import User
from ..models import Book

class ModelTests(TestCase):
    def setup(self):
        self.username = 'john'
        self.password = '123'
        self.user = User.objects.create(name=self.username,
                                        password=self.password
                                       )

    def test_create_book(self):
        Book.objects.create(artist=self.user,
                            title=“An Art Book“,
                            category=“Art”,
                            )
        self.assertEquals(Book.objects.all().count(), 1)
```

I get this error message after running manage.py test

```
Book.objects.create(artist=self.user,
AttributeError: 'ModelTests' object has no attribute 'user'
```

But it works when I put the lines from setup into the test case.
Did I miss something?

Comment: This might be some help https://stackoverflow.com/a/29442551/5919344

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The method should be called `setUp`, not `setup`.