# Django test cases - data not getting loaded into default database

Tags: python, django, testing

I am writing test cases to one of my learning project. I have added sample data via admin site, I can see that data successfully.

While writing test cases for the same model, seems data not loading into test database. I am not sure what I am missing here. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

#### todos/models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

#### todos/tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Todo

# Create your tests here
class TodoModelTest(TestCase):


    @classmethod
    def setupTestData(cls):
        Todo.objects.create(title='first todo', body='a body here')

    def test_todo_count(self):
        todo_count = Todo.objects.all()
        self.assertEqual(len(todo_count), 1)


    def test_title_content(self):
        todo = Todo.objects.get(id=1)
        expected_object_name = f'{todo.title}'
        self.assertEquals(expected_object_name, 'first todo')

    def test_body_content(self):
        todo = Todo.objects.get(id=1)
        expected_object_body = f'{todo.body}'
        self.assertEquals(expected_object_name, 'a body here')
```

#### test result

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
EEF
======================================================================
ERROR: test_body_content (todos.tests.TodoModelTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tests.py", line 23, in test_body_content
    todo = Todo.objects.get(id=1)
  File "/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 429, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
todos.models.Todo.DoesNotExist: Todo matching query does not exist.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_title_content (todos.tests.TodoModelTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tests.py", line 18, in test_title_content
    todo = Todo.objects.get(id=1)
  File "/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 429, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
todos.models.Todo.DoesNotExist: Todo matching query does not exist.

======================================================================
FAIL: test_todo_count (todos.tests.TodoModelTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tests.py", line 14, in test_todo_count
    self.assertEqual(len(todo_count), 1)
AssertionError: 0 != 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.005s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=2)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I have tested my model via shell as well

```
>>> from todos.models import Todo
>>> t = Todo.objects.create(title="this is title", body="This is body")
>>> t.title
'this is title'
>>> t.body
'This is body'
>>>
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you call `setUpTestData` instead of simple `setUp`? I am not super familiar with. setUpTestData but I think it creates new objects for each test.

Comment: @hansTheFranz, Thank you for responding. No, I just followed the name from the tutorial I used to practice.

Comment: @hansTheFranz That did the trick, I renamed to `setUp`, and it worked :D. Thank you. Please add your comment as answer.

Comment: And I think this exactly says why ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428894/django-setuptestdata-vs-setup

Answer (score 0):

Your testing database will increase the pk during the tests, even if there is only one in the db. The state rewinds, but the pk counter does not.

If you need to explicitly test primary keys, there is: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/advanced/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.reset_sequences

Because you're using a class for testing, you can just use the created todo using `self.todo`

```
class TodoModelTest(TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setupTestData(cls):
        self.todo = Todo.objects.create(title='first todo', body='a body here')

    def test_title_content(self):
        expected_object_name = f'{self.todo.title}'
        self.assertEquals(expected_object_name, 'first todo')
```

If you are curious of the pk you could try using `todo = Todo.objects.first()` and then simple `print(todo.id)` will then show you what is happening with the pk.