# The login session is not alive after setup in django unitest

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-unittest

I have the following issue. I'm following some tutorials to get some understanding of Django and I want to do now a test of a view:

`view.py`:

```py
class OwnerListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Owner
    paginate_by = 10
```

`model.py`:

```py
class Owner(models.Model):

    username = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    
    first_name = models.TextField(null=True, max_length=100)
    
    last_name = models.TextField(null=True, max_length=100)
    
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        """String for representing the Model object."""
        return self.username
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Returns the url to access a particular instance of the model."""
        return reverse('owner', args=[int(self.pk)])
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-username']
```

`url.py` (for the app):

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('owners', views.OwnerListView.as_view(), name='owners'), 
]
```

And here comes my question. I want to test the view which requires the user to be logged in. But I'd like to do that at the beggining of the test and then do all the tests that I want to do, because I think is more time/code/processing efficient.

So I create the following code:
`tests/test_views.py`:

```py
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from inventory_items.models import Owner

class OwnerListViewTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(self):
        # Create 13 authors for pagination tests
        number_of_owners = 13

        for owner_id in range(number_of_owners):
            Owner.objects.create(
                first_name=f'FirstName {owner_id}',
                last_name=f'LastName {owner_id}',
                username=f'Username {owner_id}',
            )
        
        # Login
        User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
        self.client = Client()
        self.client.login(username='john', password='johnpassword')


    def test_view_url_accessible_by_name(self):
        self.client.login(username='john', password='johnpassword')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('owners'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)


    def test_pagination_is_ten(self):
        # self.client.login(username='john', password='johnpassword')
        response = self.client.get(reverse('owners'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        self.assertTrue('is_paginated' in response.context)
        self.assertTrue(response.context['is_paginated'] == True)
        self.assertTrue(len(response.context['owner_list']) == 10)
```

So the first test runs ok beacuse I'm doing the test inside the tescase, but in the second one I comment the line, because I would like to get the login done in the setup, but it returns a 302 because it redirects to login.

Why is not kept the session if I'm setting it up in the setup function?

Comment: It seems to be because you're using `setUpTestData` instead of `setUp`. Have a read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428894/django-setuptestdata-vs-setup

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would do a change to use `setUpClass` instead of `setUpTestData`, as the second is pretty special, there's good article about it

https://medium.com/an-engineer-a-reader-a-guy/django-test-fixture-setup-setupclass-and-setuptestdata-72b6d944cdef

Moreover, if you don't test your Auth, you should use `force_login` instead

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login