# Why setUpTestData has an argument and setUp doesn't?

Tags: python, django, testing, django-testing

Pretty much the title. In django, when creating tests, we have two options, `setUp` and `setUpTestData`. I understand that `setUp` will be called each time a single test runs, while `setUpTestData` will be called only once and be used in multiple tests.

I don't understand what the `cls` does in `setUpTestData(cls)`, though. And why `setUp()` doesn' t have that argument?

Comment: **`setUp(...)`** is an *"instance method"* and thus the first argument (usually) represented as `self` whereas **`setUpTestData(...)`** is a *"class method"* and the first argument (usually) represented as `cls`. These `self` and `cls` can be arbitrary anything like `foo` and `bar` (except any reserved keywords)

Comment: Alright, but why? Why isn't `setUpTestData` an instance method as well?

Comment: Think of it in object oriented terms. You create an instance of the class, and part of that act of creation is running setUpTestData(). Then, when you run the methods of that class, setUp() is just a normal method whose name is also a shorthand for 'run this method at the beginning of other test_methods'.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @SamSparx. But, still, what is the motivation behind this? Is it faster that  way?

Comment: Aside from the speed differnces between running once at setup and running every time - there's some practical answers on the differences here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29428894/django-setuptestdata-vs-setup.  I think, also, setuptestdata was introduced in Django 1.8 whereas setup is from python unittest